# Jquery accessible sortable list utilising serialize function

Tags: jquery

I'm using this - https://codepen.io/barrytsmith/pen/kfiqj - to make an accessible sortable list but can't get serialize to work in the onDrop function - has any one any experience of it? It doesn't load the data into order.

```
        $('#sort-it ol').sortable({
        onDrop: function(item) {
            $(item).removeClass("dragged").removeAttr("style");
            $("body").removeClass("dragging");


            var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            console.log(order);
            alert(order);

            getInitialOrder('#sort-it li');
        }
    });
```

[image]

SOLEVED - by adding .get() - var order = $(this).sortable('serialize').get();

Comment: what's the problem? it works